# Frequent traveling to the US

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I live in Canada and currently I have the following travel plans to the US:

1. Aug 11-15: vacation with friends, totally for fun
2. Aug 20-24: to attend a conference and I will give a talk. I can ask for an invitation letter.

The locations are very different (east coast & west coast). Both trips I have return air tickets. My question is since the two trips are quite close in time, will CBP officers have any problem with that?  Thanks for your answers in advance.

PS: For full disclosure, earlier this year (March) I also had two short trips to US (only 2-day and 3-day stays respectively).

Comment: What's your citizenship?
Are there any other reasons you'd be ineligible for the Visa Waiver Program?

Comment: @CMaster I have a valid B1/B2 visa (not a Canadian citizen but I have legal status here).

Comment: Why would there be a problem with this? Do you not have a multiple entry visa?

Comment: Thanks @pnuts.  I do think my plans are legit and if I were a CBP agent, I would let some a travel enter.  However, as you said, they cannot be easily predicted and can be at times tough, so I thought I need to seek some advice before traveling.

Comment: @pnuts 90 days is the VWP.  B-visa holders get up to 6 months (at the discretion of the CBP officer).

Comment: @pnuts B visitors can apply to extend their stay for up to 6 months beyond the period granted on entry, so the total maximum total stay is 1 year.

Comment: @phoog  Good to know.  But I guess one really needs very strong reasons to stay for a year.

Comment: @pnuts interesting.  The 6-month figure came from a US government site, thoughI don't remember which one.  There is a CBP field manual in the internet that I think also says 6 months, but I don't remember for sure (and it is a few years old now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reside legally in Canada and have a valid multiple-entry B1/B2 visa, you have nothing to worry about unless there is some evidence that you are spending more time in the US than in Canada.  You aren't, so don't worry.

Comment: @user16416, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers